# Filetype error in older version of Power Query

Tags: powerquery, excel-2016, excel-365

I've made a report in pivot table in Excel 365 file by using the Power Query script, whose acquires data data form `.xmlx` file (previously exported from D365) by a path imported by VBA macro to named cell ("filePath").

The Power Query code starts like that:

```
let
    Ścieżka = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="filePath"]}[Content]{0}[Column1],
    Źródło = Excel.Workbook(File.Contents(#"Ścieżka"), null, true),
    AxTable1_Table = Źródło{[Item="AxTable1",Kind="Table"]}[Data],
    ...
```

Next i have some filtering and column manipulaion. I cannot share file in cause of using the business data of standard production costs lines.

The problem is that despite perfect working on PCs with Office 365, there is no way to propery runn this file on a Excell 2016. What i get is a popup window with text by second step in executing the let lines:

> [DataFormat.Error] The input couldn't be recognized as a valid Excel document.

Is there a differences in loading files between these two releases of Power Query and some guidelines to ensure the enquiry working on both?

Step by step, I excluded errors with the VBA macro. I checked the file operation on four different computers (2x D365, 2x Office 2016) with the same source data. The error is reproducible in the same software version.

I need to find a way to ensure data retrieval compatibility in different versions of Power Query.

Comment: What does `filepath` look like (you can replace any confidential information in the path with placeholders)?  Are the computers running Excel 2016 also PC's?  Or are they MAC's?  Where is the file stored?

Comment: For example: 
filepath = "C:\Users\ALM\OneDrive\Pulpit\Transakcje obliczania BOM z uwzględnieniem szczegółów_638019424338466945.xlsx"


I've tried with different localisations like Desktop, Download but always on PCs. I don't think that is a problem with slashes in path. Warrning is not about missing file, but about wrong format, despite pointing right to the same .xmlx file.

Comment: You write you are trying to open an `.xmlx` file, but the `filepath` references an `.xlsx` file. Could this be the problem?  (I've never worked with an `.xmlx` file). Perhaps a registry entry on the 2016 PC's that doesn't associate the filetypes properly?

Comment: Sorry, typo in the post. I mean .xlsx, standard new Excel files.